# How to get a background color low opacity overlay on a featured image?

Tags: css, wordpress, background, overlay

He everyone i am strugling to find a css that will work to get a overlay on my feautured image so you can see my title more clear. For the site www.quinstudio.nl/gallery. Any idea how i can get this to work?

```
? {
background: #000;
opacity: .1;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far (HTML and css for the relevant parts of the page), and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could approach this. There's no real difference in how they'll turn out; you can use whichever works better with the markup you have. The first option is a little simpler because there's no empty div being added as a color overlay.

Option 1: Make the colored background opaque, and the image partially transparent.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0cd;
  
  /* You need this line for the centered h1 below to work. */
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: block;
}

.image-wrapper h1 {
 /* Here's a trick for centering your title, if you want. */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: auto;
  
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="Kitten">
  <h1>Kitty!</h1>
</div>
```

Option 2: Make the image opaque, and put a partially transparent overlay on top of it.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  display: block;
}

.image-overlay {
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2; /* puts this div 'in front' of the image */
}

.image-wrapper h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 3; /* puts the text in front of the dark overlay */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="Kitty!">
  <div class="image-overlay"></div>
  <h1>Kitty?</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have put in the css only it did not work  When i put this in it will give a white overlay instead of black .edgt-justified-layout .edgt-ni-inner .edgt-ni-image-holder .edgt-post-image {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 2):

While @jack's answer is good, I'd like to share an alternative one that doesn't use an `<img>` element and instead uses the `:after` pseudo-element.

This allows you to use the CSS background image on the container and essentially add a fake element that has the color overlay on it:

```css
.container {
   background: url(https://loremflickr.com/320/240);
   width: 320px;
   height: 240px;
   position: relative;
}

.overlay > * {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.overlay:after {
  content: "";
  background: #0095ee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: .65;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

---

## Edit:

Your situation is a little different. You can just lower the opacity of the image and add a black background to it's parent container. Try the following:

```
.edgt-justified-layout .edgt-ni-inner .edgt-ni-image-holder .edgt-post-image img {
    opacity: .75;
}

.edgt-justified-layout .edgt-ni-inner .edgt-ni-image-holder .edgt-post-image {
    background: #000;
}
```

It will lower the opacity of the image (which will make it look "whiter", so we can add a black (or whatever color you want) background to it's parent container to compensate and darken it instead.

Comment: Thank  you for your reply how can implement this so it will connect to my feautured image.

Comment: Both my and @jack's answers are _general_ in nature. We'd need to see your HTML in order to tell you anything else since themes implement featured images differently.

Comment: Yes i see. My website link is http://www.quintyvandijk.com/gallery/ or do you need something else like my style.css file?

Comment: I've posted an update to my answer - due to the structure of your site, lowering the opacity of the image and adding a background-color to it's parent is probably the best way. Those CSS Selectors may be a bit heavy, but it should work just fine

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question i was wondering if you can help me out with that i am trying all day to get the date of the blogpost displayed under the post title can you help me out with that?

Comment: That goes beyond the scope of this question. I'd consider asking a new question with a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Each theme is structured differently, so you'll need to dig through theme files